# Generalize lines with specific points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, line, simplify, generalization

It's been a while since I was here. I have this problem now. 
I have electricity line feature class and point feature class intersecting line features. What I need to do is simplify this line feature class but effects must not effect those vertices which intersect with points. Using ArcGIS 10.2.2. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So perhaps you can 1) create a line ID per line then 2) [split lines at each point feature](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000003w000000) then 3) [generalize those lines](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001v00000006000000) then 4) [dissolve the lines together based on the line ID from step 1](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000005n000000)?